.NET MAUI PopUp CloseAsync() is not finishing
I'm trying to use PopUpService for displaying a Popup that on the one hand takes a parameter and returns one.
Unfortunately, upon returning the Popup does not seem to finish the async task and I don't know why. I assume some kind of CancellationToken is required.
Here the necessary code:
In one ViewModel the PopUp is called:
public partial class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly IPopupService _popupService;

    // ...

    public SomeViewModel(
        IPopupService popupService)
    {
        _popupService = popupService;
    }
    
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task OnCallingPopUpAsync()
    {
        var result = await _popupService.ShowPopupAsync<PopupViewModel>(
                onPresenting: viewModel => viewModel.TransferValue(true)
            );
        if (result is bool boolResult)
            Debug.WriteLine("Success!!");
        else
            return;
    }
}

In the PopupViewModel the value is received. Furthermore, in the View on can just close the PopupView via pressing a button and calling the ClosePopupCommand:
public partial class PopupViewModel : Popup
{
    public ImagePickerViewModel() {}

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task OnClosePopup()
    {
        await CloseAsync(true);
    }

    public void TransferValue(bool value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"The transferred value is {value}");
    }
}

Nonetheless, the Popup does not close.
I have tried passing in a CancellationToken (similar how it is performed in the MS Docs, like the following:
[RelayCommand]
private async Task OnClosePopup()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    await CloseAsync(true, token: cts.Token);
}

This, however, yielded an Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'A task was canceled.'
How may I resolve this?


The Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern enforces a separation between three software layers — the XAML user interface, called the view, the underlying data, called the model, and an intermediary between the view and the model, called the viewmodel.

So using CloseAsync() in ViewModel will not close the Popup.
The easiest way is to close the Popup in code behind.
Suppose we close the Popup when clicking a Button,
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    await CloseAsync(true, token: cts.Token);
}

Or if you want to close the Popup in ViewModel, you may try passing the Popup through the CommandParameter using Relative Binding,
<Button Text="click me" Command="{Binding ClosePopupCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:Popup}}}"/>

and resolve it and close it in the ViewModel,
    [RelayCommand]
    private void OnClosePopup(object o)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var p = o as MyPopupPage;

        p.CloseAsync(false, token: cts.Token);
    }


Update
If relative binding not work, you may also try x:Reference Binding expression.
Set the name of the Popup to "this",
<toolkit:Popup 
...
             x:Name="this">


...

<Button Text="click me" Command="{Binding ClosePopupCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}}"/>

and pass popup using x:Reference Binding expression and close it in the ViewModel,
    [RelayCommand]
    private void OnClosePopup(object o)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var p = o as MyPopupPage;

        p.CloseAsync(false, token: cts.Token);
    }

Hope it helps!

When I try to use the ViewModel solution (which I'd prefer), I receive upon calling p.CloseAsync(false, token: cts.Token)the ExceptionSystem.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` Do you know, why?

That's weird. It works on my side. Have you registered Popup View and View Model, builder.Services.AddTransientPopup< MyPopupPage, PopupViewModel >();?

@user25033240 If the ways in my answer don't work, may I know what .NET version and platform do you use? By the way, I also update a new way which use x:Reference binding expression.

Yes, I've registered the Popup alike // Register PupUps builder.Services.AddTransientPopup<ImagePickerView, ImagePickerViewModel>(); for the MauiAppBuilder.

I'm targeting net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 Is that what you meant?

Just tested your update! The x:Refrence Binding works!! Thank you very much!

What is dotnet and MAUI version and which platform you are testing iOS or Android?
